# WinCE 7.0 development using Windows Embedded Compact 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, compact-framework, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

I have to develop an Application for WinCE 7.0 device ([MC3200 MOBILE COMPUTER](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/mobile-computers/handheld/mc3200.html#mainpartabscontainer_2bee=warranties-support)).After googling for a while I came to know that WinCE development can be done only from VS 2005/2008 Pro(or greater).I also saw some answers here but they were too old to be considered.

When asked to the product vendor they said that I can use windows Embedded Compact 2013 and develop C# applications for WinCE 7.0 in VS 2012/2013 Pro(or greater).

From what I searched, Windows Embedded Compact 2013 is itself an OS then how can i develop for WinCE 7.0 OS using Windows Embedded Compact 2013 in VS 2013 Pro ? I am confused with this Windows naming of versions and their functionality totally.Can someone please shed some light over this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name Windows CE was used up to version 6. Since version 7 they named it Windows Embedded Compact, and its next version was 2013. You can't have both simultaneously of course, and the link with device information you provided also shows:

> **Operating system (OS)**
>
> Choice of Windows Embedded Compact 7.0 (Standard or Premium) or Android 4.1 (Premium)

(for the Windows CE history see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE)

For Windows Embedded Compact 7 (.NET 3.5) you have to use Visual Studio 2008, and for Windows Embedded Compact 2013 (.NET 3.9) you can use Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: yah already read that but wanted to know that is it possible if i download windows Embedded Compact 2013 and follow steps given in this link -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn197932.aspx and this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5cd9b2c.aspx will i be able to develop in VS 2013 Premium with msdn ?

Comment: @VishalNair The OS is called "embedded" because the required drivers are embedded into them. If the vendor has a 2013 OS for the device, then you're good to go - but as they list only Windows Embedded Compact 7 on their own website, I don't think you'll find any. I'd ask that vendor who advised you, as either he made a mistake or he can help you further.

Comment: Oh ! That's the same thing I was thinking but was confused about Windows Embedded Compact 2013 being an OS or some tool to develop CE apps in VS 2012/2013 because the Sr.Developer of the vendor himself confirmed that we can develop apps for CE7 in VS 2013 pointing me to this link -> msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn197932.aspx .Will talk with the vendor in more detail.Thanks for the help pal !